# Redirecting output of a script to a file as a background job does not output anything

Tags: bash, rake, rake-task

I have a line:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake mentions:stream > mention.log`

It outputs text to `mention.log` file.

When I try to run it as background job:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake mentions:stream > mention.log &`

it does not output anything to this file.

Can someone explain me why ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to run it while its part of a script:

a_script:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake mentions:stream > mention.log
```

then run:

```
a_script &
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake mentions:stream > mention.log 2>&1 &

It tells the process where to redirect stdout (i.e. to the file) and then redirects stderr to stdout.